# Can uploadify.js be used for mobile platforms?

Tags: jquery, mobile, uploadify

I have a site which uses uploadify.js. But when I run this website on mobile(Cellphone) this does not upload images.

Can we use uploadify.js for the mobiles phones (windows, android or any other).

If yes, how?

Comment: have you tried demos on uploadify website? http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: I tried this in opera mini simulator but this is not working.

Comment: opera mini does not support html5 i think

Comment: @Kamil I am using uploadify.js with flash support

Comment: as far as i know iphone does not support flash, android with default options also, but you can install flash on android, so i think you have to do this first

Comment: I have already implemented for web. But not working in mobile phones. So trying to figure out is this work on phones.

Comment: Opera Mini doesn't really support anything... it's not meant to be a full browser.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @jitsCode I used jQuery file upload script.You can use jQuery plugins also.

Comment: Follow this http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

Comment: Will you leave this question unanswered forever? Post your solution and accept it so that other people can apply it when facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mobile platforms which do not support the Flash uploadify.js will not work, like iPhones.It is better to use jQuery plugins.