# Ajax uploadify plugin on mobile phones

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework, uploadify

I integrated ajax uploadify plugin on web. But it is not working on mobile phones. Why?
How do I confirm it will support mobile platforms also?
I searched on the web but no any perfect answers on this.
A user having same doubt is not cleared yet. Refer

[Can uploadify.js be used for mobile platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438120/can-uploadify-js-be-used-for-moble-platforms)

Answer (score 0):

It might be wise to test your mobile website from a mobile browser, but I understand that this a difficult thing. Luckily living in the 21st century has its pros: Mobile testers!

Take a look at the following sites:

- http://mobiletest.me/ (doesn't emulate mobile)
- http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx (emulate Apple products)
- http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/overview.html (not free)
- http://jsconsole.com/ (debugging javascript on mobile device)

Hopefully that will get you going a bit.